# Can we share or transfer data from one Activity to another Activity using SharedPreference?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I have to just transfer save file path from one activity to another activity but when it comes to show the data it display null value.

**Following is the code to store data in SharedPreference:-**

```
    SharedPreferences pref= getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Recorder",0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("file_name",DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_kk-mm-ss", new Date().getTime())+".mp4");
    editor.putString("file_path",Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_kk-mm-ss", new Date().getTime())+".mp4");
```

**Retrieving data from sharedPreference:-**

```
 file_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.file_name);
    file_path = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.file_path);
    pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Recorder",0);
    editor = pref.edit();
    String fileName = pref.getString("file_name",null);
    String filePath = pref.getString("file_path",null);

    if(fileName != null){
            file_name.setText(fileName);
    }else{
        file_name.append("");
    }

    if (filePath != null){
        file_path.setText(filePath);
    }else{
        file_path.append("");
    }
```

Comment: add editor.apply(); after putting the values to preference

Comment: Yes you can, `editor.apply()` is what you are missing; although a better way to do it is to use `intent.putStringExtra()`

Comment: Also you can write `editor.commit();` after stroing the values to sharepreference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply the editor by

editor.commit():

or

editor.apply();

Answer (score 1):

`editor.apply()` is missing. You are not committing the save.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to overload the system ? you have a mechanism for passing data between activities, just send the path of the file within the intent.

In ActivityA :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("filePath", "...");
startActivity(intent);
```

In ActivityB :

```
String filePath = getIntent().getExtras().getString("filePath");
```

Comment: Actually the question ask for data transfer using preference and not by intent extra

Comment: yes, but if you want to do it the right way, thats the recommended by all means...

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can make use of SharedPreference to **Store** the information.

To pass the data from one activity to another its better to use intent.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("file_name","name");
    intent.putExtra("file_path","path");
    startActivity(intent)
```

In another Activity,

```
String fileName = getIntent().getStringExtra("file_name");
String filePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("file_path");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharedPreffernces just to share data between activities, then it's overkill.

In case data should be available after app restart your solutions is good. But if you need it only at runtime, it's better to use Intent as mentioned in other answers.

Personally, I would prefer to store it in some static variable.

Answer (score 0):

editor.commit() is missing.
Better way is to use bundle that could be set in intent and use this intent to start another activity and then fetch values from intent's bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make use of SharedPrefernces. try below code

```
     public static final String MYPREFERNCES_Example = "mysharedpref";
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor ;
     SharedPreferences sp;

    sp = getSharedPreferences(MYPREFERNCES_Example Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor=sp.edit();

    Intent i_login = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
    editor.putString("yourownkey1", yourvalue);
    editor.putString("yourownkey2", yourvalue);
    editor.putString("yourownkey3", yourvalue);
    startActivity(intent)
```

and in next activity

```
sp = getSharedPreferences(MYPREFERNCES_Example, 0);   
editor = sp.edit();  
String fn = sp.getString("yourownkey1", "");
String ln = sp.getString("yourownkey2", "");
String fbemail = sp.getString("yourownkey3", "");
```